# Different "return null" results in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

Given the following code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('[name="clickableTD"]').click(function() {
            window.document.location = $(this).attr("href");
      });
});


function Add(id) {
  
 
    var stock = "2";
 
    var quantity = prompt("SELECT QUANTITY:", 1);
  
    if (quantity == null) {
        return null;
    }
  
    else if (quantity <= stock) {
        alert("Good");
    }
 
 else if (quantity > stock) {
        alert("Over");
 }
 
 else if (isNaN(quantity)) {
        alert("NaN");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td name="clickableTD" href="javascript:Add('1')">
      <a>Click</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If the user returns a null value (by clicking cancel) using **Chrome** as the browser nothing happens as would be expected.

But if the user is using **Firefox** he will be redirected to the url Add() and display null as a text string on the screen.

Why does Firefox react differently than Chrome?

Comment: Please show the whole code, so we can see how this function is being used.

Comment: What is `function_name()`, and how is it related to the code you posted?

Comment: @adamdc78 What does the type have to do with it, he's not testing that?

Comment: You still haven't shown how `Function_Name()` is being called.

Comment: You know that SO now has a built-in replacement for jsfiddle, don't you? Click on the `[ < > ]` tool in the SO editor to open the snippets editor, where you can create executable HTML/JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been having trouble finding a detailed specification of how `javascript:` URLs work, and what they're supposed to do when the code returns something other than a string or undefined. It looks like Chrome and FireFox have taken different approaches in this case. Chrome treats them like `undefined`, and doesn't change the page contents. FF does various things: if it returns `null` it displays the string `null`; if it returns an object with a single property, it displays the value of that property.

Use `return void(0)` or `return undefined` instead of `null` for better compatibility between browsers.

Comment: I could just delete the if quantity == null clause. But why are there different reactions depending on the browser?